# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl

I have a windows service in a VM. It is calling an API hosted in another server. When I call that api from my windows service, it is giving me error saying :

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Now I know that if I add this line before calling the api, it will work fine.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```

But I do not want to change my code and deploy it again. Is there any way I can do something in the VM where windows service is hosted, like trusting the certificate or something , which will resolve this?

Any help in this regard is really helpful. Thanks.

I know this question is asked multiple time, but all the solutions require me to either change in the server where api is hosted or change my code to add above line. I'm looking for a solution where I can change in the client machine rather than anywhere else.

Comment: well, what is the reason that it is invalid? if it is trust chain, then sure, you could trust the CA/chain on the node, but that potentially opens up other risks if the CA is not well protected; if it is dates, or the wrong hosts, etc, then: probably not

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks so much for the quick reply. I do not see any other risks as these all machines are well protected in the company's network. Can you tell me how to trust the certificate on the node?

Comment: do you have the CA cert as a pfx? should only need the public part

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this a few times. It could mean a few things:

- Unsupported protocol(s) (SSL/TSL)
- No matching cipher(s)
- .NET Framework version < 4.6.1 needs special code

For the first two options, you could use nmap to determine the server's supported list of protocols and ciphers:

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <host>
```

Once having the list of supported protocols/ciphers, you can then check your own on your client machine using a free tool called [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and verify that you have enabled matching protocol/cipher combinations.

For the last option, if you are running anything less than .NET Framework 4.6.1, you may need to add:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

I don't really suggest setting the protocols strictly as above (since TLS 1.3 is around the corner). Should always try to let windows determine the highest security for you. Sometimes certain evils are necessary to move forward. You can always revisit it later.

This has helped me solve this particular problem. Hopefully it will aid you with yours.